# monitoring plugin check_http cert expiration check

Tags: ssl, nagios

[root@chi plugins]# '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http' '-C' '15,30' '-I' '99.830.700.184' '-S' '-p' '443'

SSL OK - Certificate 'localhost' will expire on 2018-12-14 02:20 +0000/UTC. HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found - 226 bytes in 0.156 second response time |time=0.155850s;;;0.000000 size=226B;;;0

I need to suppress The HTTP 404 warning. If there's another plugin that can do this, I'd like to know about it. (I can't change anything on the webserver.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same plugin, but add `-e 404`, so it will look like:

```
[root@chi plugins]# '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http' '-C' '15,30' '-I' '99.830.700.184' '-S' '-p' '443' '-e' '404'
```

The `-e 404` flag suppress 404 error code.

Comment: I probably need to pipe the output to sed or awk like so:

   `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http' '-C' '15,30' '-I' '99.830.700.184' '-S' '-p' '443'| sed 's/HTTP.*//'`

but I've never done this with Icinga2 (or Icinga 1.14) so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you try this Nagios script - https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/HTTP/check_ssl_cert/details ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the tcp command (check_tcp plugin) instead. I should have been using check_tcp all along.

In my /etc/icinga2/zones.d/global-templates/global-commands.conf file I added

```
apply Service "HTTPS/8443: Secure Management Interface" {
  import "generic-service"
  check_command = "tcp"
  vars.tcp_port = "8443"
  vars.tcp_ssl  = true
  vars.tcp_timeout = 60
  vars.tcp_ipv4 = true
  vars.tcp_ipv6 = false
  vars.tcp_timeout = 30

  assign where host.vars.devtype == "dadada"
```